# Usefulness of ability to calculate $m^{p+q}$ with RSA

Tags: rsa

I noticed that with only an RSA public key, it is possible/tractable to calculate $m^{p+q} \pmod n$ for any $m$ without knowing $p$ or $q$.  Namely, $m^{p+q} \equiv m^{n+1} \pmod n$.  (This follows from $\phi(n) = n - p - q + 1$ and the order of all multiplicative subgroups $\mod n$ dividing $\phi(n)$.)

Is this useful for anything?